# Pick the cumulative max value in Panel data by groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, max

I have a panel dataset with thousands of observations. Let me simplify things:

```
library(dplyr)
x1 = c(NA,NA,NA,5.1,5.0,5.4,5.15,4.9,5,6)
x2 = c(5.9,5.85,5.8,6,5.95,5.98,5.99,6.1,6.15,6.14)
df = data.frame(countrycode = c(replicate(10,"ITA"), replicate(10,"UK")),
                year = c(replicate(2,2010:2019)), LogGdp = c(x1,x2))
```

Then, I'm looking for an efficient way to pick the maximum value of a given variable (by country code) which updates when a new maximum is found. The outcome should look like the record column below

```
z1 = c(NA,NA,NA,5.1,5.1,5.4,5.4,5.4,5.4,6) 
z2 = c(5.9,5.9,5.9,6,6,6,6,6.1,6.15,6.15)
df = data.frame(countrycode = c(replicate(10,"ITA"), replicate(10,"UK")),
                year = c(replicate(2,2010:2019)), LogGdp = c(x1,x2), record = c(z1,z2))
```

That's my attempt:

```
df %>%
  group_by(countrycode) %>%
  mutate(record = cummax(LogGdp))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace missing values with `-Inf`, use `cummax()` to find cumulative maxima, and then convert `-Inf` back to `NA` with `na_if()`.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(record = replace(LogGdp, is.na(LogGdp), -Inf) %>% cummax %>% na_if(-Inf),
         .by = countrycode)

#    countrycode year LogGdp record
# 1          ITA 2010     NA     NA
# 2          ITA 2011     NA     NA
# 3          ITA 2012     NA     NA
# 4          ITA 2013   5.10   5.10
# 5          ITA 2014   5.00   5.10
# 6          ITA 2015   5.40   5.40
# 7          ITA 2016   5.15   5.40
# 8          ITA 2017   4.90   5.40
# 9          ITA 2018   5.00   5.40
# 10         ITA 2019   6.00   6.00
# 11          UK 2010   5.90   5.90
# 12          UK 2011   5.85   5.90
# 13          UK 2012   5.80   5.90
# 14          UK 2013   6.00   6.00
# 15          UK 2014   5.95   6.00
# 16          UK 2015   5.98   6.00
# 17          UK 2016   5.99   6.00
# 18          UK 2017   6.10   6.10
# 19          UK 2018   6.15   6.15
# 20          UK 2019   6.14   6.15
```

---

An alternative with `Reduce` + `pmax`.

**Note:** Here must be `pmax()` instead of `max`, because `pmax(NA, NA, na.rm = TRUE)` returns `NA` as expected, but `max(NA, NA, na.rm = TRUE)` returns `-Inf` with an annoying warning message.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(record = Reduce(\(...) pmax(..., na.rm = TRUE), LogGdp, accumulate = TRUE),
         .by = countrycode)
```